# Check if deployment exists on slot Staging

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy a package on a role using `UpgradeBySlotAsync` on `IDeploymentOperations`' `Deployments`. When the deployment doesn't exist, it throws saying: 'A virtual network site cannot be added or removed during deployment update or upgrade'.

If I want to check on deployment's existence using `GetBySlotAsync`, it also throws when the deployment is not there.

Is there a way to check whether there is a deployment on Staging using `IDeploymentOperations` type? Something similar to `Get-AzureDeployment` in Powershell.

Comment: Can you specify the specific nuget package and version which you're using?

Comment: @juvchan: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.12.3.1

Comment: So basically you want to check the deployment existence of your VM or Cloud Service? It will be much helper if it's clearer